# Github desktop not executing, error Segmentation fault (core dumped) in Ubuntu 16.04 TLS

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, github

I am new to Ubuntu. In the past I used Windows. I installed the Github-desktop in Ubuntu using following commands:

```
sudo snap install github-desktop --beta --classic
```

Installed successfully and worked 3 - 4 good but next day when I trying to open github desktop its not executing and I found error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I do not know how to fix it, I have reinstalled many times but it's not working. Can you please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: You have tagged 14.04, but then your heading says 16.04.  Which are you running?

Comment: @guiverc ubuntu 16.04

Comment: As a workaround USE THE PREVIOUS VERSION:

To install the previous version (which works and tested bionic ubuntu 18.04 LTS AND 19.10 eoan) and remove the version you tried to install:

``wget https://github.com/shiftkey/desktop/releases/download/release-2.0.4-linux1/GitHubDesktop-linux-2.0.4-linux1.snap;
snap remove github-desktop;
snap install GitHubDesktop-linux-2.0.4-linux1.snap --classic --dangerous``